# How to quit MATLAB process using C# and COM?

Tags: c#, matlab, com, reference-counting

I have a this code that calls a MATLAB function (displayFigure.m) from a C# client. Each time I update the .m file, the changes are not reflected when the C# program is rerun.

```
public void CallMLfunc(){
    MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
    matlab.Feval("displayFigure", 0, out result, input);
    matlab.Quit();
}
```

Tried to terminate the MATLAB.exe process using

```
matlab.execute("quit;");
```

and will get the following an unhandled exception: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`.

After force quitting the program I rerun it again an displayFigure.m (version 2) is reflected. Is there another to quit the MATLAB process?

Answer (score 0):

There's a MATLAB.exe in the process list for the COM object. Sometimes there's a visible window you can close. Sometimes there isn't. You may have more than one MATLAB.exe, especially if you are debugging and the MATLAB editor is open, you'll have that instance running as well. The `matlab.Quit();` should terminate the MATLAB.exe associated with the COM object, but if there is an Exception during the `matlab.Feval()`, or breakpoint, etc., it might not execute. When I have that problem, I terminate the MATLAB.exe with the highest PID.